# How to rename Flask WSGI App during development?

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, virtualenv, pipenv

I would like to know how can I change the name of the Flask WSGI App during the development stage.

Using the [Flask Mega-Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) as reference, I was able to successfully setup a "Hello World" app.
*Digressions* from the tutorial:

1. Use `pipenv` as my Python virtual environment manager (instead of `venv`)
2. Name of the app is `astronomer.py`.

Now, I want to build on top of the existing app and customize the code to my requirements; starting with the app name that I have defined in the `.flaskenv` file as `FLASK_APP` env var.
Accordingly, I have updated the name of the root level Python script from `astronomer.py` (in the tutorial) to `galielo.py` (for my use). After changing the corresponding value of `FLASK_APP` and restarting the flask server via `$ pipenv run flask run`, the app crashes with the following error:

```
$ pipenv run flask run                                                                                                                                                                                                             [12:29:33]
 * Serving Flask app "astronomer.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 302-012-958
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2019 12:29:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kshitij10496/.local/share/virtualenvs/galileo-iQPdbs28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'astronomer'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kshitij10496/.local/share/virtualenvs/galileo-iQPdbs28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 338, in __call__
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
  File "/Users/kshitij10496/.local/share/virtualenvs/galileo-iQPdbs28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 326, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/kshitij10496/.local/share/virtualenvs/galileo-iQPdbs28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/kshitij10496/.local/share/virtualenvs/galileo-iQPdbs28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 314, in _load_app
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/Users/kshitij10496/.local/share/virtualenvs/galileo-iQPdbs28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/Users/kshitij10496/.local/share/virtualenvs/galileo-iQPdbs28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/Users/kshitij10496/.local/share/virtualenvs/galileo-iQPdbs28/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 250, in locate_app
    raise NoAppException('Could not import "{name}".'.format(name=module_name))
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "astronomer".
```

**Debugging**

- After logging into the virtual env and checking for the value of the env var `FLASK_APP`, I get the old value of `astronomer.py`. This explains why the application is not starting. However, I'm not able to understand why this is happening?
- I even tried using "eager-loading" the app using: `$ pipenv run flask run --eager-loading`
  Still, the app does not start with the same error message ofcourse.

I was able to solve this manually by unsetting the env var `FLASK_APP` from within the virtual env and restarting the flask server. I'm curious to know about why the app is not loading the file `.flaskenv` at initialization and if there is an automated way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With `Pipenv`, I think things are a little bit different when it comes to environment variables. As [per the documentation](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#automatic-loading-of-env), there is a builtin mechanism for loading a `.env` file:

> If a .env file is present in your project, $ pipenv shell and $ pipenv run will automatically load it, for you

So I guess you should rename your file from `.flaskenv` to `.env` and then safely remove the `python-dotenv` dependency.